# Разделение gui и логики программы

Tags: winapi, gui, qt, c++

Как можно отделить визуальный интерфейс приложения от алгоритма/логики. В qt получается что код строится вокруг GUI, это неприятно >.,.< Хотелось бы писать код и потом связывать его с интерфейсом, но слишком мало опыта в таких вещах. Что можно использовать для этого? Кроссплатформенность не так важна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи существует ряд схожих паттернов проектирования. В частности, это MVC, MVP и MVVM. Не имею опыта работы с Qt (думаю, знающие люди подскажут), однако эти паттерны, как и любой уважающий себя шаблон проектирования, независимы от конкретных языков и технологий. Пару слов о самом известном из них - MVC. Состоит, как можно видеть, из трех основных частей - модели (M), представления(V) и контроллера (C). Модель отвечает за реализацию логики приложения, представление - за отображение модели, а контроллер является связующим звеном между первыми двумя. Здесь важно помнить следующие особенности - модель должна быть независима как от представления, так и от контроллера. Тем самым повышается возможность повторного использования модели, уменьшается связность кода и становится более удобным тестирование бизнес-логики. Второй очень важной особенностью является то, что контроллер должен быть не более чем посредником между моделью и представлением, а потому категорически не рекомендуется сваливать на него функции модели (такое бывает, когда модель вырождается до сущности, отвечающей за работу с данными, а контроллер берет на себя всю бизнес-логику). Такого "раздувания" контроллеров обычно зовется Fat Stupid Ugly Controllers (или ТТУК - Толстые Тупые Уродливые Контроллеры). Это крайне нежелательно, поскольку сводит на нет преимущества MVC-подхода.

Напоследок простой совет (как "выжимка" из вышеозначенного словоблудия) - никогда не запихивайте логику в обработчики событий. Это очень дурная практика, от каждого случая применения которой умирают десять маленьких невинных котят

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Давно мучает этот вопрос, без явного разделения получается каша, а мне больше приятны красивые решения с понятной и логичной архитектурой, а не индусский код в каждом обработчике событий.